# How do we call this classical theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do we call this classical theorem:

> Given any integers $a$ and $b$, with $a\gt 0$, there exist unique
>   integers $q$ and $r$ such that $b=qa+r$, $0\le r\lt a$.

Is there a standard name for this theorem? I've already heard names such as division algorithm, euclidean division, euclidean algorithm, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is commonly called the Division Algorithm.

See:https://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Math2721/Week9-10.pdf

From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division:

> The computation of the quotient and the remainder from the dividend and the divisor is called division or, in case of ambiguity, **Euclidean division**. The theorem is frequently referred to as the **division algorithm**, although it is a theorem and not an algorithm, because its proof as given below also provides a simple division algorithm for computing q and r.

Comment: Wikipedia calls Euclidean Division.

Comment: @user42912 see my edit

Comment: It's clear now, thank you!